# C++ Returning Multiple Types as Reference

Tags: c++, templates, reference

Ok so I'm trying to setup a template method that returns a reference of an undetermined type based on a parameter request.  Everything looks fine but it keeps telling me that no overloaded method of the provided template method exists when I call it.  The code looks something like this:

```
class IObj {
    public:
    int id;
}
class ObjOne : public IObj {}
class ObjTwo : public IObj {}
class ObjThree : public IObj {}

enum ObjectTypes {
    O1Type,
    O2Type,
    O3Type
}

class ObjManager {
    public:
    std::vector< std::unique_ptr<ObjOne> > O1Holder;
    std::vector< std::unique_ptr<ObjTwo> > O2Holder;
    std::vector< std::unique_ptr<ObjThree> > O3Holder;

    ObjManager() {}

    template <class T>
    T& GetObject(int oID, ObjectTypes oType) {
        if(oType == ObjectTypes::O1Type) {
            for(int i = 0; i < O1Holder.size(); i++) {
                if(O1Holder[i]->id == oID) {
                    return *O1Holder[i];
                }
            }
        }
        else if(oType == ObjectTypes::O2Type) {
            for(int i = 0; i < O2Holder.size(); i++) {
                if(O2Holder[i]->id == oID) {
                    return *O2Holder[i];
                }
            }
        }
        else if(oType == ObjectTypes::O3Type) {
            for(int i = 0; i < O3Holder.size(); i++) {
                if(O3Holder[i]->id == oID) {
                    return *O3Holder[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<ObjManager> oManager(new ObjManager());

    ObjOne& a = oManager->GetObject(0, ObjectTypes::O1Type);
    return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine, and I can make a method that returns a reference to the object stored in the vectors if I return their specific type, but I'm trying to reduce the redundancy of making many functions to return each different type.  So I wanted to make a templated method that would return an object type based on which ever type I requested.

It's not giving me any errors it just keeps underlining the *->* in the expression *oManager->GetObject*, and tells me there is no overloaded method for the template method call.  Specifically it states **"no instance of function template 'ObjManager::GetObject' matches the argument list, argument types are (int, ObjectTypes)"** even though I'm passing an integer and ObjectTypes:: into the function's parameter list.  I've looked all over for an answer to this but have not been able to find a similar situation to draw experience on.

**EDIT:** Sorry should have specified that this is a precursor to a vast list of vectors, I just put 3 of them for simplicity.  That's why I'm trying to make a single function that can handle the return of different types so that I don't have to make a return function for every vector I create.  And the purpose of returning a reference to the specified type is because each derived type will have unique data that is not in the base class, so I'm pulling the objects for editing.

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned that there are objects of each type in the vectors, they are not empty.  I just didn't show that in the code.

Comment: Why does `GetObject` need to be a template? Why doesn't it just return `IObj &`?

Comment: Because IObj does not have the same variables as the derived objects, and the point of returning the object reference is to set those unique variables.

Comment: Whats the name of this file?

Comment: @JoshC. You've misunderstood how templates work: Return type does not take part in type deduction. Even if it did, `T` has to be deduced as a single type for the entire instance of a function and your code can't know what `objType` is at compile time, so each of your three returns would have to be compiled into each <T> variant of the function, meaning that for any value of T, two of the returns would have the wrong return type.

Comment: As kfsone noted, return type does not take part in type deduction. Consequence, on the other hand, is that you have to write `getObject<ObjOne>()` anyway. So wouldn't it be more convenient to have three different getters (getObjOne, getObjTwo, getObjThree)?

Answer (score 2):

As @tobi303 commented, you should definetly use the template Parameter T in your GetObject class. Then you would actually avoid repeating yourself as the Compiler will generate the code for you that you have repeated 3 times

```
template <class T>
    T& GetObject(int oID) {
            for(int i = 0; i < OHolder<T>.size(); i++) {
                if(OHolder<T>[i]->id == oID) {
                    return *OHolder<T>[i];
                }
        }
```

While you would have to define a OHolder Template function, too.

Comment: Excellent idea !  But it would still get the same error message due to template type deduction on return type.  A little edit is therefore required.  See [online compilation problem](http://ideone.com/J34brA)

Comment: That's correct, but rather than passing the enum value that is now used for the if else branches, the type can be explicitly passed as a template Parameter. With C++14 it should be possible to use an auto return type, isn't it? "If the return type of the function template is a placeholder (auto or decltype(auto)), that return type is a non-deduced context and is determined from the instantiation." [Cppreference.com]

Comment: I'm affraid the auto won't solve the problem as there would still be no way to deduce the template's type.  I'd just use a dummy parameter for the type deduction to occur.  Or do you have a better alternative ?

Comment: Ah of course, there's no template in the signature, sorry. Yea, there is something left to do but I have no alternative :(

Comment: @Christophe, personally, I'd go with explicitly telling the Compiler about the template type rather than forcing Auto deduction with a dummy param, like "ObjOne& a = oManager->GetObject<ObjOne>(0);" i think States intent a little bit clearer.

Comment: Oh yes !  That's an alternative as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the return type of a function based on runtime information (such as your parameters), because they are obviously unknown to the compiler.

If you will **always** know at compile time which object type you are going to choose, you can use a trick:

Step 1: Turn your enum into a couple of empty structs:

```
struct O1Type {};
struct O2Type {};
struct O3Type {};
```

Step 2: Instead of using `else if`s, use function overloading:

```
ObjOne& GetObject(int oID, O1Type) {/* TODO*/}
ObjTwo& GetObject(int oID, O2Type) {/* TODO*/}
ObjThree& GetObject(int oID, O3Type) {/* TODO*/}
```

You can now use

```
ObjOne& a = oManager->GetObject(0, O1Type());
```

(or, even better `auto& a = oManager->GetObject(0, O1Type());`)

Comment: Seems like that adds an extra layer of maintenance - the tag list has to be kept in sync with the type list. You might as well just have a GetObject<T> which takes the type you want returned, and then specialize GetObject to return the specific OXHolder. `auto& a = oManager->GetObject<ObjOne>(0);`

Comment: You mean I should use a function specialization and specify the type when I call for the GetObject method?

Answer (score 0):

**Root cause**

Template argument type deduction can't be solely based on the return type of the function.

**On the way to a solution**

You could therefore add a dummy function argument to transfer the type information:

```
template <class T>
T& GetObject(int oID, ObjectTypes oType, T&x) {
    ...
}
```

and in `main()`:

```
ObjOne& a = oManager->GetObject(0, ObjectTypes::O1Type, a);
```

Then the template type can be deduced.

But this will not solve your problem.  This type deduction is at compile time, so that all the possible returns of the function should return the same type (or something that can be converted to it).

This is not the case of your code, which will lead to other compilation errors (see [online failure](http://ideone.com/u3VOy1)).

**The solution**

The only workable solution is that you determine the common denominator to return.  Make the function a non-template function returning an `IObj&`:

```
IObj& GetObject(int oID, ObjectTypes oType) {
...
}
```

You should then manage the return object as a polymorphic obhect as well.  As the return is by reference, this is fine (i.e. no slicing occurs). The returned reference will really refer to the object returned, whatever its derived type could be. But you'd have to redesign your calling code for polymorphism:

```
IObj& a = oManager->GetObject(0, ObjectTypes::O1Type);
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/rhyXjf)

But this is somewhat clumsy because you indicate in an enum the expected type, but then end with a reference to a parent that you can't handle so easily.

**Conclusion**

As you indicate in the function the expected return type, you'd better go for the solution in Yussuf's rexcellent answer, but applying the technique of the dummy argument for type deduction.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to use both run-time polymorphism AND the compile-time (template) polymorphism. It doesn't work this way. You cannot return multiple types from the SAME METHOD.
What you probably want to do is to either define a method like @yussuf described, or to fully start using run-time polymorphism - in which case you don't need three containers, and the type becomes part of the object ID.
I concur with @yussuf's approach. Just do that, it probably will solve your problem.
I would also recommend to use a hash / map instead of performing linear search, but this is a different story...

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after much research, I have determined the best way to accomplish this is to create a custom container class like so:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Base {
    public:
    int ID;

    Base(int id) { ID = id; }
}

class A : public Base {
    public:
    int X;

    A(int id) : Base(id) {}
}

class B : public Base {
    public:
    int Y;

    B(int id) : Base(id) {}
}

template <class T>
class MyContainer {
    private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> internalContainer;

    public:
    MyContainer() {}
    ~MyContainer() {}

    void CreateItem(int id) {
        std::unique_ptr<T> newItem(new T(id));
        internalContainer.push_back(std::move(newItem));
    }

    T& GetItem(int id) {
        for(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>::iterator it = internalContainer.begin(); it!= internalContainer.end(); ++it) {
            if((*it)->ID == id) {
                return **it;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    MyContainer<A> AList;
    MyContainer<B> BList;

    AList.CreateItem(0);
    BList.CreateItem(0);

    A& AOne = AList.GetItem(0);
    B& BOne = BList.GetItem(0);

    AOne.X = 10;
    BOne.Y = 20;

    std::cout << std::to_string(AOne.X) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::to_string(BOne.Y) << "\n";
}
```

Let me know your opinions on if this is acceptable or if it can be improved!  :)